# Why is the sensor value at the optocoupler wrong?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, pcb, opto-isolator, pullup

I am using six inductive sensors in my circuit. Four of them are working fine, but two sensors are showing very weird behaviour.

I am using an optocoupler to read their output to the MCU for isolation:

[image]

Sensor 1 problem: When I measure the voltage on the optocoupler's phototransistor when there is no output on the sensor it shows only 1.2V, but it should show 3.3V because it is pulled up to 3.3V.

Sensor 2 problem: When there is output from the sensor, the voltage on the optocoupler should be tending to zero, but it stays at 3.2V.

I am using the same circuit for all six sensors.

Pull up resistor value is 4.7K

Comment: Do not use caps.

Comment: @nick_n_a why other sensors are working fine

Comment: Did you install diode ZD21 backwards? Also, normally ground is down and power is up.

Comment: Try swapping things round to see if the fault follows the sensor or the interface circuit.

Comment: He means do not use all-capital-letters in your title. He doesn't mean don't use capacitors (for example). Well, at least I think that's what he means.

Comment: Don't use ALL CAPITAL LETTERS in your title.  It's considered rude!

Comment: This schematic is horrible to read and prone to error. Try to put GND down and power nets ups. This week improve readability and also well make it easier to help you

Comment: What is the CTR of the opto?  I'd look it up, but I'm not sure what the part number is.

Comment: IMO, ZD 24V not needed, actually it can even burn your sensor, ZD 3.3V definitely not needed,. 1N4004 not needed,....

Comment: @Aaron optocoupler:PC817 ,CTR MIN. 50% at If=5mA, Vce=5V

Comment: Fig. 6 on datasheet shows CTR curve. You're operating around the 480% point.  So if the sensor is leaking a small amount, you can be activating the opto.

Comment: You should not use figure 6 in the data sheet to design to.  If anything, use the table labeled "Electro-optical Characteristics".